# VBA If, And inequality operation not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data, the first column is a category for which the rows looks like A, A, A, B, B, B, B, C, C, ... then other columns one of which is a positive or negative number for each row (this number differs within categories). I am trying to define a function that takes each a category A, B, C ... and checks whether the first and and last instance of A is positive or negative then spits out a result on a single line. However, the final stage of checking inequalities doesn't seem to be working. It seems to ignore the And operator and just uses the first condition of the And as the only one.

```
Public Function TickerCurve(Tickers As Range, Ticker As String) As String

Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Integer
Dim StrA, StrB As String
Dim col As Range
c = 0

For Each col In Tickers.Rows
    d = ActiveCell.Row
    If col.Value = Ticker Then
        StrA = Cells(d, 2).Value
        StrB = Cells(d + 1, 2).Value
        If StrA = StrB Then
            c = c + 1
            d = d + 1
        Else
            If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(d - c, 16).Value > 0 And Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(d, 16).Value > 0 Then
                TickerCurve = "USD above EUR"
                c = 0
            ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(d - c, 16).Value < 1 And Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(d, 16).Value < 0 Then
                TickerCurve = "EUR above USD"
                c = 0
            ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(d - c, 16).Value < 0 And Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(d, 16).Value > 0 Then
                TickerCurve = "Cross"
                c = 0
            ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(d - c, 16).Value > 0 And Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(d, 16).Value < 0 Then
                TickerCurve = "Cross"
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next col


End Function
```

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvoWZ.png)

[Uses (new)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u3sL.png)

Comment: Can you show the Data in a Screenshot ? And How are you using the Function ?

Comment: What data type is column 16?

Comment: Column 16 data is the difference between two numbers that are vlookup from another sheet - e.g. 14.6 or -4.62.

Comment: Have added pictures at the bottom with the data (a lot of hidden columns) and how I am trying to use it.

Comment: Maybe the Cause is `Activecell` , which remains the same. Move the line `d = ActiveCell.Row` outside the loop. that might work. Because in every Iteration it's setting the value of  d = 2.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. It's moving down the column and detecting category changes well enough, it just doesn't seem to be outputting the right outcome given the inequalities in the Else statement. Thanks though

Comment: @OwenPaterson ,, Try the Answer Below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the Macro to a Button before Proceeding. I hope it helps, not sure about the conditions being applied as you intend, but this should work.

**Try this:**

```
Sub tickercurve()

Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim cel As Range
Dim varKey As Variant
Dim result As Range
Dim tickers As Range
Dim tickercurve As String
Set tickers = Application.InputBox("Select the Tikers Range", Type:=8)
Set result = Application.InputBox("Select the result start Range", Type:=8)

For Each cel In tickers.Columns(1).Cells
    i = i + 1
    If Not dict.Exists(cel.Text) Then
        dict.Add cel.Text, cel

    Else
        Set rngTemp = Union(cel, dict(cel.Text))
        dict.Remove cel.Text
        dict.Add cel.Text, rngTemp
    End If
Next cel
i = 0
For Each varKey In dict.Keys

    With Range(dict.Item(varKey).Address)

            If Cells(.Cells(1, 1).row, 16).Value > 0 And Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).row, 16).Value > 0 Then
                tickercurve = "USD above EUR"
            ElseIf Cells(.Cells(1, 1).row, 16).Value < 1 And Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).row, 16).Value < 0 Then
                tickercurve = "EUR above USD"
            ElseIf Cells(.Cells(1, 1).row, 16).Value < 0 And Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).row, 16).Value > 0 Then
                tickercurve = "Cross"
            ElseIf Cells(.Cells(1, 1).row, 16).Value > 0 And Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).row, 16).Value < 0 Then
                tickercurve = "Cross"
            End If

    Cells(result.row + i, result.Column).Value = varKey
    Cells(result.row + i, result.Column + 1).Value = tickercurve
    i = i + 1

    End With

Next varKey


Set dict = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mikku, thanks. However, it still doesn't work. I realise that I may have actually been unclear in my use example. I have updated the image. I want to end up with a single category - so it takes all the A's looks at the first and the last number within the A's rows and if both are positive spit out one output, another for negative, and another if they are differently signed. So the end result is a row with one A and the output, then a row with one B and the output and so on.

Comment: @OwenPaterson .. Try the Answer